# Signing error in Google Cloud via Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

When I try and call `file.getSignedUrl({ action: 'read', expires: '03-01 2500'
    })`, I am returned the error of `Failure from metadata server`.

This is code that was previously working (a few days ago) so my gut says something funky happened in the permissions? Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: If you need help diagnosing an unexpected problem like this where the documentation doesn't help, please contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: I'm seeing this same error but from a GCP Function. Works fine locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the real cause of the problem.

In the IAM & Admin portal within Google Cloud, the member representing my Firebase Project (i.e. `myproject-memberId@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com`) only had the `Owner` permission.

I had a flawed understanding, and assumed that this was the highest level of auth, [which it evidently is not](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles). At some point, I must have changed it to this "higher" permission, without realizing I removed the `Editor` permission.

To SOLVE my problem I had to simply add the `Editor` permission back to my member in the IAM & Admin portal in Google cloud for my project.

Another instance, of human error.